# Cómo crear correctamente el interior del for para que me muestre la suma del tamaño total

Tags: bash, bucle-for

Este es mi primer Script, me han dicho que cree un Script para calcular el tamaño total de un conjunto de ficheros de un directorio.
he creado un Script y en su interior he puesto lo siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
suma=0;
archivos='ls -l|tr -s" "|cut -f5 -d" "';
for i in '$archivos';
   do
      tamanyo='$suma + $i'
   done
echo "La suma es: $tamanyo"
exit 0
```

Necesito usar *ls -l|tr -s" "|cut -f5 -d" "* preciso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes entender lo que devuelve el comando que usas para poder trabajar con su resultado.

Lo ideal es separarlo en pedazos, ya que el mismo es una [*tubería*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuber%C3%ADa_(inform%C3%A1tica)) de llamadas cuyo resultado es *algo* con lo que debes luego trabajar para obtener el dato esperado.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea encontrar el valor en [bytes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) del espacio o tamaño de los ficheros/archivos de un directorio. Se debe usar la siguiente orden o comando:

```
ls -l| tr -s " "| cut -f5 -d " "
```

Vemos que se trata de 3 órdenes diferentes:

- [ls -l](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ls-invocation.html#ls-invocation): *Muestra información acerca de los FICHEROs (del directorio actual por defecto).* Con la opcíon `-l`: *utiliza un formato de listado largo*. Es decir, muestra una lista de los archivos en el directorio.

Veamos una captura para ver la diferencia entre `ls` y `ls -l`:

[image: Diferencia entre comando "ls" y comando "ls -l"]

Podemos notar la diferencia claramente. En la parte superior de la imagen se ve que la lista de archivos se muestra de forma lineal, ajustando los nombres al tamaño de la salida, en la parte baja donde se usa el comando `ls -l` vemos que los archivos se muestran uno por cada línea y se muestra un detalle de los mismos, como el tipo de permisos, el propietario, el tamaño que ocupa en el sistema de archivos, etc.

- [`tr -s " "`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/tr): *Traslada, aprieta y/o elimina caracteres de la entrada estándar, escribe en salida estándar.* La opción `-s` (*--squeeze-repeats*) *reemplaza cada secuencia de un carácter repetido que se enumera en el último CONJUNTO especificado, con una sola aparición de ese carácter.* Es decir, cada grupo de caracteres " " (espacio) es reemplazado por un único espacio.

Por ejemplo:

```
> str=".    donde    ."
> tr -s " " <<< $str
> . donde .
```

Vemos claramente que los espacios adicionales son eliminados dejando sólo 1.

Si ejecutamos este comando justo después del primero, esto es lo que obtendríamos:

[image: Salida luego de aplicar 'tr -s " "']

- [`cut -f5 -d " "`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/cut): *Extrae las partes seleccionadas de cada FICHERO en la salida estándar: Sin FICHERO, o cuando FICHERO es -, lee la entrada estándar.* Con la opción `-f 5` selecciona solamente estos campos (*fields*), en este caso el 5 campo es el que muestra el tamaño del archivo (los campos se enumeran empezando en uno). Con la opción `-d " "` definimos cuál será el delimitador de campos, en este caso nuestro delimitador será un espacio: " ".

La salida de todo el comando se puede apreciar de la siguiente forma:

[image: Salida de todo el comando]

Ahora, ¿qué representa esta salida? ¿Es un String? ¿Es un Array?.

Lo cierto es que se trata de una cadena, y su primer elemento es nulo (seguro no lo habías notado).

¿Cómo sacamos los valores de dicha cadena?

Cabe destacar, que para asignar el resultado de un comando a una variable en un script bash se hace uso de: `variable=$(<comandos aquí>)`.

Tal como lo tienes en tu pregunta, tu variable es simplemente un `string`:

```
# esto es un string que contiene: ls -l|tr -s" "|cut -f5 -d" "
archivos='ls -l|tr -s" "|cut -f5 -d" "';

# esto es el resultado del comando: ls -l|tr -s" "|cut -f5 -d" "
archivos=$(ls -l| tr -s " "| cut -f 5 -d " ");
# notemos el espacio dejado después de cada opción:
# -s " "
# -f 5
# -d " "
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Existen muchas formas de hacerlo, yo usaré `read`: *Leer una línea desde la entrada estándar y separarla en sus campos.*

Como el resultado del comando anterior son varias líneas, debemos leer *mientras* existan lineas por leer:

```sh
while read bytes
do
  ...
done <<< "$archivos"
```

¿Qué estamos haciendo? En primer lugar estamos separando cada linea de nuestra cadena y su valor lo estamos almacenando en una variable llamada `bytes`. La entrada para el comando `read` la estamos redirigiendo con `<<<` y le indicamos que será nuestra variable `archivos`.

Como ya nuestra cadena viene limpia de todo el proceso anterior, lo que vamos a almacenar en la variable `bytes` es el valor de cada linea que se corresponde precisamente con el tamaño en *bytes* de cada archivo de nuestro directorio.

Solo queda realizar la operación aritmética de suma dentro de nuestro bucle `while`:

```
suma=$((suma+bytes));
```

Nótese que en la expresión anterior no se dejan espacios entre los operandos y los operadores.

Con esto, tu variable `suma` tendrá el valor calculado del tamaño total de los archivos en el directorio.

El script completo podría verse así:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
clear;
suma=0;
archivos=$(ls -l| tr -s " "| cut -f 5 -d " ");

while read bytes
do
  suma=$((suma+bytes));
done <<< "$archivos"

echo "El tamaño total de los archivos es: $suma bytes";

exit 0;
```

Existen otras formas de obtener el resultado a partir del comando que indicas en tu pregunta. Tu aproximación intenta recorrer un `array`. Pero lo cierto es que tu variable no es un `array`.

Comment: Gran respuesta, muy bien detallado

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda!! Gracias a tu explicacion he logrado completar mi script, he de decir que no lo he hecho exactamente igual pero me ha servido de gran ayuda y como guia, gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Si bien la respuesta de @Mauricio es buena sólo sobre los comandos que ya usabas, creo que la clave está en profundizar en los conceptos de `bash` como expansiones y evaluaciones que hace. Además que usaré el `for` de `bash` como especificaste en tu duda.

Me parece que se puede hacer uso de tu propio script e incluso se le puede quitar algunas cosas.

El script completo es este:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

suma=0

for i in $(ls -l | tr -s " "|cut -f5 -d" ")
   do
        ((suma += i))
   done

echo "La suma es: $suma"
```

Y listo; eso sería todo lo que necesitas.

A continuación le pondré su explicación más a detalle dentro del código:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

suma=0

# "for" itera sobre cualquier tipo de expansión.
# Hay ocho tipo de expansiones en bash: 
#
# - command substitution: Usando $(lista de comandos) o `lista de comandos` se manda
#                         a la salida sólo el resultado de la ejecución de la
#                         "lista de comandos".
#
# - tilde expansion: con el uso de ~ para expandir el contenido
#                    de la variable $HOME o $PWD, según el caso.
#
# - brace expansion: con el uso de {} para expandir sobre rangos, listas
#                    dentro de las llaves.
#
# - parameter expansion: con el uso de $ se expande el contenido de
#                        una variable y se puede modificar.
#
# - arithmetic expansion: con el uso de $(( expresión aritmética )) evalúa la expresión
#                         dentro de $((  )) y lo asigna.
#
# - process substitution: con el uso de <(proceso) o >(proceso) sustituye la salida de procesos.
#
# - word splitting: la shell registra el valor de las variables expandidas que NO esten
#                   entrecomilladas y las separa por el IFS (internal field separator)
#                   es decir, lo que separe los campos. Por defecto es <espacio><tab><nueva línea>.
#
# - pathname expansion: bash escanea cada palabra en busca de "*", "?", "[" y sobre esto expande
#                       los archivos que sigan el patrón.
#
#
# Una vez sabiendo las expansiones, utilizamos un "command substitution".
#                 |      que luego se separaran con un "word splitting"
#                 |      y "for" iterará sobre esta expansión de tamaños.
#                 |    
#                 |      Recuerdo que el "word splitting" actua porque NO
#                 |      entrecomillamos la salida del "command substitution".
#                 |
#         ________|___________________________
#        |                                    |
for i in $(ls -l | tr -s " " | cut -f 5 -d " ")
   do
    # Aquí utilizamos algo llamado evaluación aritmética.
    #
    # Esta evaluación se dará entre doble paréntesis o lo que le siga a "let 'expresión aritmética' ".
    #
    # Lo que hacemos en esta evaluación es incrementar la variable "suma" el valor de la variable
    # "i". Este valor se acumula en la variable suma.
    #
    # Nota como no es necesario un parameter expansion utilizando "$suma" e "$i" ya que dentro de la
    # evaluación aritmética se expanden los nombres de las variables.
        ((suma += i))
   done

echo "La suma es: $suma"
#                 |
#                 |
#          Ya sólo hacemos uso de parameter expansion.
#          para devolver el valor acumulado en la
#          variable "suma".
#                 |
#                 |___ Como aclaración: aquí, como si se entrecomilló
#                      la variable "$suma", entonces NO habrá un 
#                      "word splitting".
```

Por supuesto: esto lo obtuve de el manual de `bash` que puedes consultar con `man bash`.

Sé que se te pidió que utilizaras `ls -l | tr ...` pero creo que es importante que se sepa que se puede tener un resultado más preciso con otros métodos, como:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -printf "%s\n" | awk '{tamano_total+=$0}END{print "El tamaño total de los archivos es: "tamano_total}'
```

Donde utilizas poco `bash` y más las opciones de los programas del entorno.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar el `awk` que te traiga todos los tamaños de los directorios y después lo sumas.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
suma=0;
for i in $(ls -l | awk '{print $5}');
   do
      ((suma += i))
   done
echo "La suma es: $suma"
exit 0
```

Comment: Hola muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda!! Pero debo usar preciso el codigo que indico en mi pregunta, lo que pasa es que no me han explicado lo que es awk en clase y el maestro dice que deberia usar ls -l, es correcto el codigo de mi script? Como se podria mejorar?

Answer (score -1):

Intenta con

```
for entry in "$search_dir"/*
  do
    echo "$entry"
  done
```

fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437452/how-to-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-in-a-shell-script

Comment: Hola muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda! aunque debo usar ls -l, lo que a mi me falla es el contenido de dentro de do y done, este como seria?